# Jolt transformer throwing OutOfMemoryError Exception

Tags: json, jolt

Whenever I am running this spec and input, the jolt transformer is getting stuck. It is neither getting timeout nor sending any exception.
[image: Text]

**Steps to Reproduce:**
Copy and paste the below payload in https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Input

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "style_properties": {
      "style_fields": [
        {
          "name": "Rishi",
          "label": "Rishi multi",
          "type": "multi_select",
          "value": [
            "banita",
            "ajith"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "style_properties": {
          "display_id": "payload[0].object.display_id",
          "style_fields": {
            "*": {
              "value": {
                "*": {
                  "@1": "payload[0].content.changes"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I have tried running this with v0.1.6 on my local. I am getting OutOfMemoryError.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:267)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:241)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:233)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:464)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.shiftr.ShiftrTraversr.handleFinalSet(ShiftrTraversr.java:55)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.traversal.BaseTraversalStep.traverse(BaseTraversalStep.java:54)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.traversal.BaseTraversalStep.traverse(BaseTraversalStep.java:67)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.traversal.BaseTraversalStep.traverse(BaseTraversalStep.java:67)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.traversal.BaseTraversalStep.traverse(BaseTraversalStep.java:67)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.traversal.BaseTraversalStep.traverse(BaseTraversalStep.java:67)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.traversal.BaseTraversalStep.traverse(BaseTraversalStep.java:67)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.traversal.BaseTraversalStep.traverse(BaseTraversalStep.java:67)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.traversr.Traversr.set(Traversr.java:148)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.PathEvaluatingTraversal.write(PathEvaluatingTraversal.java:101)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.shiftr.spec.ShiftrLeafSpec.apply(ShiftrLeafSpec.java:139)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.shiftr.spec.ShiftrCompositeSpec.apply(ShiftrCompositeSpec.java:218)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.applyKeyToComputed(ExecutionStrategy.java:327)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.applyKeyToLiteralAndComputed(ExecutionStrategy.java:317)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.access$200(ExecutionStrategy.java:26)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy$4.processList(ExecutionStrategy.java:222)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.process(ExecutionStrategy.java:284)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.shiftr.spec.ShiftrCompositeSpec.apply(ShiftrCompositeSpec.java:222)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy$1.processMap(ExecutionStrategy.java:44)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.process(ExecutionStrategy.java:281)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.shiftr.spec.ShiftrCompositeSpec.apply(ShiftrCompositeSpec.java:222)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.applyKeyToComputed(ExecutionStrategy.java:327)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.access$100(ExecutionStrategy.java:26)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy$3.processList(ExecutionStrategy.java:183)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.ExecutionStrategy.process(ExecutionStrategy.java:284)
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.shiftr.spec.ShiftrCompositeSpec.apply(ShiftrCompositeSpec.java:222)
```

I have created a issue on jolt repo too.
https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/1205

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you please add what output you want to get ?

Comment: Btw, there's no `display_id` element within the input. That is stated on the LHS in the spec.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for the reply. The issue is we are getting no response and not even timeout. This is working fine if "value" is a string. But if I can "value" to an array of strings, it is getting stuck. You try it yourself once at https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception.